# How to implement fluid font size using pure CSS

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have text wrapped in `<div>`s, and would like to make the whole thing fluid including the font-size of the text, i.e. the text resizes itself in response to the size of the containing element.

I came across a [Javasript + CSS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467934/css-javascript-fluid-font-size), but just wondering if it is possible to do so with pure CSS?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no current solution using CSS only.  You'll have to use JavaScript or JavaScript+CSS.

Comment: I came across the same problem and finished with a javascript solution (actually it was Gquery as I was working with GWT)... I don't think a pure CSS solution exists...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, look at CSS 3 media queries.  You can provide different style rules depending on the viewport width.  This includes altering the font size.

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {font-size:15px;} something like this.. this is how responsive designs are built.

Comment: @Jim, with media queries, is the change continuous with respect to the width change?

Comment: No.  You can [make it less sudden using CSS transitions](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/css-transitions-media-queries/), but if you want it to be changing continuously, you'll have to use a JavaScript solution like [FitText](http://fittextjs.com).

Comment: This is limited. If the text your trying to shrink is dynamic you can't predict the width you should assign in your media query. At least as far as I can tell, you still need JavaScript.

Answer (score 34):

While Jim has given you accurate information, it strays from the question asked slightly. Responsive design (@media queries) can alter the text according to screen size. From what I understand, you were asking if there is a pure CSS solution for fluid text size (continual resizing of text during window size changes).

Here is a link to css-tricks explanation of new [font sizing techniques](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/). Please be aware this is new and older browsers will most likely have some issues, and that even newer ones (Chrome + Safari) are still not bug-free.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

**Edit- added code**

Comment: I like this one :)

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

You can't have fluid font sizes, but you will when [viewport-percentage lengths](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) are widely available.

## Long Answer

You have to understand these two terms: **responsive** and **fluid**.

**Responsive** means you make your stylesheet respond differently to different window sizes. This is done by using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). While responsive is one of the *hippest* words in web design, it mostly means hardcoding CSS for different absolute lengths until you drop dead of boredom.

**Fluid** means you work with relative length units such as percentages. When you work with relative length units, every size is calculated automagically.

### Example

Let's say you have a `<div>` inside the document body and you want it to fill half of the window.

The **responsive** solution is this:

```
@media (max-width: 1px) {
  body > div {
    width: 0.5px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 2px) {
  body > div {
    width: 1px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 3px) {
  body > div {
    width: 1.5px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 4px) {
  body > div {
    width: 2px;
  }
}

/* Repeat until you reach gigabytes and hit operating systems' file size limitations. */
```

And the **fluid** solution:

```
body > div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

### So?

What limits us today is that there is no wide support for viewport-relative length units. What you can do is drop the whole idea of "pure CSS **fluid** font sizes" and go **responsive**.

Comment: according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units , we now can use viewports units in all major browser !

Answer (score 1):

use calc with media query for a responsive and fluid font

```
@media screen and (min-width: 25em){
  div {  
    font-size: calc( 16px + (24 - 16) * (100vw - 400px) / (800 - 400) );
  }
}
```